# Find all polygons containing points specific criteria

Tags: postgis

I have two tables (PostGIS), one containing points, and the other containing polygons.

Right now i have this query for finding polygons (Laravel framework):

```
        $polygon = DB::connection('pgsql')
        ->select(DB::raw("SELECT row_to_json(fc)
             FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
             FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type
                , ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom,4326))::json As geometry
                , row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT areal) As l
                  )) As properties
               FROM jbb2013 As lg WHERE gid = 1208749 OR gid = 692891 OR gid = 993224 OR gid = 1171857 OR gid = 1176873) As f )  As fc;")
            );
```

With some work i get the results as GeoJSON, i then send that to Leaflet.

As you can see i specify the the polygons by id. That's not what i want to do. I'd like to use the other table containing points and find the points by a specific customer_id.

So something like this:
Find all points that belong to a specific customer_id
Use those points in a ST_Contains query to find the polygons that contain the points.
The resulting GeoJSON should then only contain the polygons found by the query.

Result (jbb2013 is the polygons table and samples is where the points are stored):

```
$polygon = DB::connection('pgsql')
        ->select(DB::raw("SELECT row_to_json(fc)
     FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features
     FROM (SELECT 'Feature' AS type
        , ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(lg.geom,4326))::json AS geometry
        , row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT areal) AS l
          )) AS properties
          FROM jbb2013 AS lg, (SELECT geom FROM samples WHERE customer_id = : customer_id) AS pts WHERE ST_Intersects(lg.geom, pts.geom)) AS f )  AS fc;"),
            array('customer_id' => $customer_id)
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be too alarmed by the GeoJSON producing SQL -- I know how cross-eyed it can make one. Ultimately, you have a table jbb2013 in the final FROM clause, and you want to limit that to those points that it intersects based on a customer_id, so you can do a standard spatial join, as a sub-query where you select only those points that match the particular customer_id, using ST_Intersects in the WHERE to limit the results. I don't know what you points table is called, so I have called it points.

```
$polygon = DB::connection('pgsql')
    ->select(DB::raw("SELECT row_to_json(fc)
         FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
         FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type
            , ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom,4326))::json As geometry
            , row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT areal) As l
              )) As properties
           FROM jbb2013 As lg, (SELECT geom from points where customer_id in (1,2,3) as pts WHERE ST_Intersects(lg.geom, pts.geom) As f )  As fc;")
        );
```

All the json aggregate functions make such queries hard to read, but if you just focus on the final FROM/WHERE, you can do what you want normally.

Comment: I got it working, see original post for finished query. And a final question, if id like to search for more criteria, like the field year in samples table. Id like to only find samples from a specific customer_id and a specific year. How would i add that to the query? When i try the column year is not found..

Comment: WHERE customer_id = : customer_id AND year =: year. What format is your year column in. If it is a datetime/timestamp, you can use extract(year from date/timestamp) to get just 2015.

Comment: The problem seems to be that my column has a capital Y in Year. All the different columns in the table has some capital letters, and needs to have it. In pgAdmin 3 the query works when i write "Year". But in Laravel that won't work, since the whole SQL statement is in side " ". Is there a quick solution that does not involve changing all the column names?

Comment: I don't use Laravel, but in other languages I've used, Python/Java, you have to escape the " if you are passing it as part of a sql statement. \"Year\"

Comment: Worth an up vote :-) or am I being too cheeky

Comment: My rep is to low :(

Comment: Try now.  :-) How do you like Laravel?

Comment: There you go! Nice. Well, I'm quite new to Laravel, and web developing for that matter. Laravel and the community around it has made it a lot easier for me.  Certainly theres other frameworks that would do the same thing. But i like Laravel. But I'm always on the look for other interesting stuff!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    polygons.*
FROM
    polygons,
    points
WHERE
    ST_Contains(polygons.wkb_geometry, points.wkb_geometry AND
    points.id IN (SELECT your condition);
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but how do i build that into the query i posted? I'm not that experienced in multiple FROM query's. Thanks!