# subtraction points from polygon

Tags: postgis, polygon

I have two polygons created at **st_concavehull(st_collect(geom), 0.99)**
and I wonder how to extract some points from union area... example below
[image]

I have no idea how to achieve this but I think it's possible.

*Postgres 9.5 / PostGIS 2.2.1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found answer:

```
      SELECT st_concavehull(st_collect(v.g_point), 0.99) AS geom
      FROM 
      ( SELECT zw.geom AS g_point
        FROM v_1 zz, v_2 zw
        WHERE zz.ec_b = 1 
        AND st_contains(zz.geom, zw.geom) 
        AND (zw.mag IN ( SELECT v_2.mag FROM v_2 WHERE v_2.mag = 'ec_a'))) v;
```

[image]

Last answer in:

[Find all polygons containing points specific criteria](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152748/find-all-polygons-containing-points-specific-criteria/152749#152749)

was very helpful